# Google sheets, using conditional formatting to match consecutive duplicates

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, formula, repeat, conditional-formatting

Does google sheets have a way of using conditional formatting to highlight duplicates, but only if they appear consecutively? For example, if I was to use the following spreadsheet:

Column A
Row 1 | Apple
Row 2 | Tomato
Row 3 | Car 
Row 4 | Car
Row 5 | Bus
Row 6 | Apple
Row 7 | Apple
Row 8 | Car

Is it possible to use a formula that would highlight rows 3 and 4, and 6 and 7?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at Conditional Formatting, and IF statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom formula:

```
=A1=A2
```

Apply to

```
A1:A100
```

Or Formula:

```
=OR(A2=A3,A2=A1)
```

Apply to:

```
A2:A110
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to adapt this code to fit my needs perfectly :)

Comment: how do you go more times in a row than 2? so that it only catches like 8 in a row?